# Does anyone know a library similar to Openinviter but for connecting your asp.net site to social networks

Tags: asp.net, social-networking

we are currently developing a website which will heavily involve connections to several social networks. I name a few (facebook, youtube, flickr, google contacts, windows live contacts, twitter,...)

i know (from collegues) that a library exists for php. called openInviter (http://openinviter.com)

though this site has to be in asp.net and probably with the CMS Umbraco (http://www.umbraco.org)

Instead of targetting each site trough its own (or custom community build) library we were wondering if anyone knows a similar library that target all or many social networks at once. Greatly simplifying the work and complexity of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you're looking at doing with the Social Networks, you might want to check out [YQL - Yahoo! Query Language](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/) - this allows you to work with one API to access a whole host of supported and custom APIs, which might well simplify things for you.

Comment: we didn't use this as we had no time to investigate this,
but we did review this after the project ended and are plannign to use the YQL in 1 of the next projects thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen [RPXNow](https://rpxnow.com/)? There is a .NET library available.

Comment: that seems interesting, i will check it out this afternoon. thanks.
however i do have the feeling that it does not cover the invite proces, but is more taking over the whole login system instead of inviting (using your google contacts to invite friends, etc...)

that is what i thought of it at first glance though, i will go over the featurelist and create a testproject this afternoon so we'll see what the exact options are then.

thanks